# Notification can not display correctly when app in background ( React Native )

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that using Firebase push remote notification, one client send notification message like below:

```
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'to' : 'token',
                'notification' : {
                    'title' : ' ' + this.currentUser.email + ' send you a message !',      
                    'body' : text
                },
                'data': {
                    'senderName' : this.currentUser.email,
                    'senderUid': this.currentUser.uid 
                }

            })
```

and one client implement the method that receive notification :

```
           firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
                    const showNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                        .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                        .setTitle(notification.title)
                        .setBody(notification.data.text)
                        .android.setChannelId('channel_id_foreground')
                        .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
                    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(showNotification)
            });
```

When my app running on foreground, the notification show normally, but when in background, it can receive in notification tray, but it not display that notification to the screen of device.

**This is how the notification show:**

[image: issue]

**I want the notification can display like:**

[image: correct]

Addition: If I close app by swipe out and send the notification, my app is going to be crashed.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: The problem was clearly. If using notification message and the app is in background, the listener **onNotification** can not be triggered. The notification just show in notification tray.

Comment: Additional: This line **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'** maybe make the app crashed if received a notification when app has been closed/swiped.
To solve that change to : **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'** or lower

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you guys found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [RN Firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/introduction), when your app is in the background or closed, the notification is handled and displayed by the OS, so your onNotification() method is never called, so the notification channel is never set.  According to [the android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels) notifications without a channel will not appear.

Here's what worked for me: if you want the notification to appear as a heads-up notification in android, modify your message body to include your channel ID, like this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
        'to' : 'token',
        'notification' : {
            'title' : ' ' + this.currentUser.email + ' send you a message !',      
            'body' : text
        },
        'data': {
            'senderName' : this.currentUser.email,
            'senderUid': this.currentUser.uid 
        },
        'android': {
            'priority': 'high',
            'notification': {
                'channel_id': 'channel_id_foreground',
            },
        }
    })
```